# ssh multiplexing & python: Will it work like this?

Tags: python, ssh

Preconditions:

- I want to execute dyamic multiple commands via ssh from python on one remote machine at a time
- I couldn't find any existing modules matching my "flavour" (If you care why, see below (*) ;))
- Python scripts are running local on a Ubuntu machine

In general for single "one action calls" I simply do a native ssh call using `subprocess.Popen` and it works fine.

But for multiple subsequent dynamic calls, I don't want to create a new ssh connection for every command, even if the remote host might allow it. I thought of the following solution:

1) Configure my local ssh on Ubuntu to use multiplexing, so as long as a connection is open, it is used instead of creating a new one (https://www.admin-magazin.de/News/Tipps/Mit-SSH-Multiplexing-schneller-einloggen (Sorry, in german))

2) Creating an ssh connection by opening it in a running background thread, where in itself nothing is done, besides maybe a "keepalive" if necessary, or things like that, and keep the connection open till it's closed (i.e. by stopping the thread). (http://sebastiandahlgren.se/2014/06/27/running-a-method-as-a-background-thread-in-python/ )

3) Still executing ssh calls simply via `subprocess.Popen`, but now automatically using the open connection due to the ssh multiplexing config.

Should this work, or is there a fallacy alert?

---

(*)What I don't want:

- Most solutions/examples I found used paramiko. On my first "happy path" it worked like charm, but the first failure test resulted in an internal AttributeError (https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/issues/1617) and I don't want to build anything on this.
- Other Libs i found like i.e. http://robotframework.org/SSHLibrary/SSHLibrary.html don't seem to have a real community using them.
- pexpect....the whole "expect" concept gives me the creeps and should in my opinion only by used if there's absolutly no other reasonable reason ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you've proposed is fine, but you don't even need to keep an ssh connection running in a background thread. If you configure `ControlMaster` (for reusing an existing connection) and `ControlPerist` (for keeping the master connection open even when all other connections have closed), then new `ssh` connections will continue to use the shared connection (as long as they happen before the `ControlPersist` timeout).

This means that if you set up the `ControlMaster` configuration external to your code (e.g., in `~/.ssh/ssh_config`), your code doesn't even need to be aware of the configuration: it can just continue to call `ssh` normally, and `ssh` will take care of reusing the connection.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation on how it really works! Followed this https://blog.scottlowe.org/2015/12/11/using-ssh-multiplexing/ , verified with "-v"....nice!